# How to get the datatype of column from the sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

1. I want to get or retrieve the datatype of a particular column where
   the list is created in a sharepoint list.

   ```
   Can you help me for doing the task?
   ```

Comment: You should need to elaborate description your question. also be showing that What have you tried?

Comment: I have created sharepoint list with number of columns,i want that columns datatatype i have tried with the following code                                                                SPField datafield = selectedlist.Fields["Attachments"];
SPFieldType fieldtype = datafield.Type;
string type1 = fieldtype.GetType().ToString(); and also i tried with                                                               SPList list = web.Lists["my list"];
SPField field = list.Fields["particular"];
SPFieldType fieldType = field.Type;

Comment: ok.look at @rich's answer.you should doing like that.than if you have doubt you should edit your question with your code. so other users understand your proper question and easy to help you :)

Comment: Hi jigs,i have tried with @richs code but i coulnt get the datatype properly,any other way to try it out?

Comment: have you got exception on that?

Answer (score 2):

See [SPField.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.type.aspx) (or [SPField.TypeDisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.typedisplayname.aspx)).

```
SPList list = web.Lists["my list"];
SPField field = list.Fields["particular"];
SPFieldType fieldType = field.Type;
string fieldTypeName = field.TypeDisplayName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [Rich Bennema's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444349/641833) (referencing the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RunTime version 16 libriaries and using the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client name space):

```
using (ClientContext cont = new ClientContext(SharePointUrl))
{
    cont.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, SecurePassword);

    FieldCollection fields = cont.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointListName).Fields;
    cont.Load(fields);
    cont.ExecuteQuery();

    var results =
            fields.Select(
                f => new
                {
                    f.InternalName,
                    f.TypeDisplayName,
                    TextMaxLength = (f is FieldText) ? ((FieldText)f).MaxLength : 0,
                    FieldChoices = (f is FieldChoice) ? ((FieldChoice)f).Choices : new string[0]
                }
            );
}
```